# To store date after using afterSetExtremes of Highcharts.stock

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

How can I store dates after using afterSetExtremes of Highcharts.stock.

```
xAxis:{
        events: {
            afterSetExtremes:function(event){
                console.log('---- Date from Chart Object after setting Extremes');
                console.log(new Date(event.min));
                console.log(new Date(event.max));
            }
        },
        type: 'datetime'
    },
```

Used this to get the selected date from navigator highcharts stockchart and want to store the date in a variable whenever date changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to create some variables in a higher scope and assign the values to them:

```
var fromDate;
var toDate;

Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
    ...,
    xAxis: {
        events: {
            afterSetExtremes: function(event) {
                fromDate = new Date(event.min);
                toDate = new Date(event.max);

                ...
            }
        },
        type: 'datetime'
    },
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/cs8q45nw/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.events.afterSetExtremes